# laravel change request after upload

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Trying to update my request after uploading a file : (Laravel 5.3)

`$path = Storage::disk('s3')->putFile($destination, $request->file($name)); // works
$request->merge(array($name => $path)); // doesn't work
$myModel->update($request->all())`

I know i can't replace a File by a string in my request, so how am i supposed to do it ?

Saw a lot of posts on that but common, must be an easier way than :

`$res = $request->except($myInputFileName) // turn it into array
$res[$myInputFileName] = $path`

Any pretty solution ?

Edit : not for now : work with request as an array

Answer (score 2):

Why don't simply try this

```
$inputData = $request->all();
$path = Storage::disk('s3')->putFile($destination, $request->file($name));
$inputData[$name] = $path;
$myModel->update($inputData);
```

Comment: Yep i know i can to it this way by turning my request in an array (as i said in my post)
I just thought there was a better way : like one where the pathname of my file input would change automatically

Comment: @r.flipo, when you do that, you're using a lot of additional memory, because you're duplicating almost all request data from Request object.

Comment: anyway i'll have to $request->all() tu update my model

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
$request[$name] = $path;
```

However I doubt you want to use `$name` as column name, so maybe you want to save `$name` and `$path` to columns with names like `file_name` and `file_path` for example? Then do this:

```
$request['name'] = $name;
$request['path'] = $path;
```

You can check `$request` contents after that with:

```
dd($request->all());
```

Comment: @r.flipo, what exactly doesn't work? Do you get any error?

Comment: Nope, but as i said in my post you can't change a request file in a request string. So it doesn't change my request

Comment: @r.flipo, just tried updated code, it works just fine.

Comment: using laravel 5.3.18, still doesn't work with your update :( $request['picture'] is an instance of UploadedFile, its pathName is private, and i can't override it into a string. Thanks for your time, i'll go with arrays !

Comment: @r.flipo, you didn't say anything about overriding uploaded file. It works for me in 5.3 when I'm overriding or adding new simple data like strings. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Usually after you upload the fine, you need to keep it's name in a DB which will work if you'll use code from my answer.

Comment: i didn't explicitly said it, but :  $request->file($name) is an instance of UploadedFile. I was trying either to change its pathName, or override this request parameter into a string. Both are not possible, so a workaround is to convert the request to an array (then override is possible)

Comment: @r.flipo, well, in you question you're doing this `$request->merge(array($name => $path));` which has nothing to do with `$request->file()`. Also, I still don't get why are you even trying to override it. You want to keep filen ame and file path, right? So, my code is working here. Duplicating whole request data into an array just to add a key => value pair before persisting that data is a bad idea because of additional memory usage.

Comment: I want to update my user, wich has a file 'picture' as a  property. I want to $user->update($request->all()). In my request i have a file i uploaded with a wrong pathname. So i have to change this input in my request before i can update